# is XSS in Content-Disposition possible?

Tags: xss

There is a web application that can upload HTML files and also download the uploaded file.

When I upload an HTML file containing the script tag and download it, the response is as follows.

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Date: Fri, 02 Jul 2021 01:11:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 39
Connection: close
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.html"; filename*=UTF-8''test.html
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY

<script>alert(1)</script>
```

Is there a security problem that can execute the script tag when the response is as below?

Comment: no, that doesn't result in an html context.

Answer (score 1):

XSS is when the attacker can execute its own script inside the context of a different side and thus can act within the origin of this site - hence **cross-site** scripting.

In your example instead the HTML file gets downloaded to disk due to the `Content-Disposition` and nothing happens. If the user explicitly clicks on the file to execute it, then it will be likely loaded into a browser and the script will be executed. But since the file was loaded from disk it will be executed within an empty origin, i.e. not associated with any domain.
Because of this it might result in script execution, but it is not XSS.